# Filter dataframe for a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe of that kind.

```
    num person                  cash
0   1   personone               29
1   1   persontwo               81
2   1   personone:              17
3   1   personone               75
4   1   personone and persontwo 62
5   1   personone's friend      55
```

I am using the following code to filter a dataframe based on vector of strings.

```
people = ["personone", "persontwo"] 
pattern = r"\b{}\b".format("|".join(people))

df[df["person"].str.match(pattern)]
```

The problem is that the code produces a bit more than I need. When I check for `df["person"].unique()` it gives me an array of:

```
array(["personone", "persontwo", "personone:", "personone ", "personone and persontwo", "personone's friend"], dtype=object)
```

Even though I used the word boundaries `\b`.

The outcome I would like to achieve is: combine `personone`, `personone:` and `personone`  (the last one with the space at the end). And produce the output of:

```
    num person    cash
0   1   personone 121
1   1   persontwo 81
```

I.e. combine the three variants of `personone` and disregard its all other appearances. The `cash` for `personone` is the sum of 29+17+75=121.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to match with optional `\W` instead of `\b` and force begin and end string:

```
people = ["personone", "persontwo"] 
pattern = r"^\W?({})\W?$".format("|".join(people))

s = df["person"].str.extract(pattern,expand=False)

df[s.notna()].groupby(['num',s])['cash'].sum()
```

Output:

```
num  person   
1    personone    121
     persontwo     81
Name: cash, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking is not entirely clear. For instance, why are you dropping the case `personone and persontwo`?

Anyway, one way to proceed is to create a `flag` variable that flags the good observations, such as

```
df['flag'] = df.person.str.contains('personone:?$')
```

and then you simply sum

```
df.loc[df.flag == True, 'cash'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^` and `$` to limit the matches:

```
>>> people = ["personone", "persontwo"]
>>> patt = fr"^({'|'.join(people)}).?$"
>>> (
      df.groupby(df.person.str.extract(patt, expand=False))
        .agg(cash=('cash', 'sum'), num=('num', 'first'))
        .reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
    )
   num     person  cash
0    1  personone   121
1    1  persontwo    81
```

Comment: Use `'sum'` instead of `sum` in `agg`. The later is Python's and is not vectorized.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks! Completely overlooked it.